# How to filter/disable exceptions being logged in WCF trace?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, trace

1. Is there a way to prevent a type of exceptions from being logged in the WCF trace?
2. And even better, is there a way to prevent *one* particular exception (I mean one exception being thrown at a specific code line) from being logged?

**Explanations:**

I am working on two Windows service (A) & (B). On service (A), I have enabled WCF trace in my *app.config* file, as follows:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" 
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener" 
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData="C:\WCF-log.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

On this service (A), I have some code used to detect if the other service (B) is down, that looks like that:

```
try {
    serviceB.Ping(); // Exception is thrown here when serviceB is down, and 
                     // logged in the C:\WCF-log.txt file
} catch {
    // Manage failed ping (log...)
}
```

Now, the service (B) can be sometimes down, and that's normal. I would like those raised exception not to be logged in the WCF trace, because they are already treated by my application, and I want to have to look into the *C:\WCF-log.txt* file only if there is a "real" problem.

Comment: yes you can write a custom filter e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.filter.aspx and in the filter you'd try to look for things in the trace (like values in the stack trace or the specific error) to filter out the value. But I don't have time to write a working example.

Comment: @MatthewMartin Thank you, **Milan** has provided a code sample below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add filter type in trace listener configuration as below

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning"
                    propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners >
                    <add name="traceListener"
                         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                         initializeData="C:\WCF-log.txt" >
                        <filter type="FilterExceptions"/>
                    </add>                  
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

And the FilterException type should inherit System.Diagnostics.TraceListener and override ShouldFilter method as below

```
 public class FilterExceptions : TraceFilter
    {
        public override bool ShouldTrace(TraceEventCache cache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string formatOrMessage, object[] args, object data1, object[] data)
        {
            // Add exception filter in below if when event type is error
            if (eventType == TraceEventType.Error)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! I just add to write the filter as the following: `<filter type="MyAssembly.FilterExceptions, MyAssembly"/>`, or else my code threw an exception "*The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception*", with its InnerException being "*Couldn't find type for class FilterExceptions*".